# C++. Функция удаления из хеш-таблицы

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Разрабатываю хеш-таблицу, которая работает с объектами структуры Item.
Пытаюсь сделать метод для удаления объекта из таблицы по ключу, но объект всеравно остаеться. Подскажите в чем ошибка.

Структура Item:

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Item
{
    Item *next;
    string name;
    int age;

    Item(string n, int a) : name(n), age(a) { }
};

#endif // ITEM_H
```

Класс Hash

```
#ifndef HASH_H
#define HASH_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "item.h"

class Hash
{
    private:
            vector<Item*> table;
            int hash(string key);

    public:
            Hash();
            ~Hash();

            void push(string name, int age);
            void dell(string name);
            Item *find(string name);
};

#endif // HASH_H
```

Его методы:

```
#include "hash.h"


int Hash::hash(string key)
{
    int hashsum = 0;

    for(size_t i=0; i<key.length(); i++)
        hashsum += key[i];

    return hashsum % table.size();
}

Hash::Hash()
{
    table.resize(50);

    for(size_t i=0; i<table.size(); i++)
        table[i] = nullptr;
}

Hash::~Hash()
{
    table.clear();
}

void Hash::push(string name, int age)
{
    int hash_index = hash(name);
    Item *person = new Item(name, age);
    Item *place = table[hash_index];

    if(!place)
    {
        table[hash_index] = person;
        return;
    }

    while(place->next)
        place = place->next;

    place->next = person;
}

void Hash::dell(string name) // ?
{
    Item *search = this->find(name);

    if(search)
    {
        delete search;
        search = nullptr;
    }
}

Item* Hash::find(string name)
{
    int hash_index = hash(name);
    Item *result = table[hash_index];

    if(!result)
    {
        cout << "Element not found!" << endl;
        return nullptr;
    }

    while(result->name != name)
    {
        if(!result->next)
        {
            cout << "Element not found!" << endl;
            return nullptr;
        }

        result = result->next;
    }

    return result;
}
```

main-функция:

```
#include "hash.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Hash table;

    table.push("John", 20);
    table.push("Li", 18);
    table.push("iL", 55);
    table.push("Simon", 24);

//    Item *search = table.find("Li");
//    if(search) cout << search->age << endl;

    table.dell("John");

    Item *se = table.find("John");
    if(se) cout << se->age << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Давайте посмотрим на метод `dell`.

```
Item *search = this->find(name);

if (search)
{
    delete search;
    search = nullptr;
}
```

Вы обнуляете локальную переменную `search`, и какой это имеет эффект на таблицу? Никакого. Вам нужно удалить найденный `Item` **из вашей таблицы**. Вы же убиваете ваш `Item`, но в таблице всё ещё есть ссылка на мёртвый `Item`. То есть следующая попытка поиска обращается к мёртвой памяти, в которой может располагаться случайное значение.

В реальности вы должны удалить найденный `Item` из односвязного списка (для этого обычно используют двойной указатель или указатель на предыдущий элемент), и возможно, если ваш bucket стал пустым, обнулить соответствующий элемент `table`.

(Код не даю, задание выглядит как учебное.)

---

Кроме того, у вашей программы неопределённое поведение из-за того, что вы не инициализируете поле `next` у `Item`. Добавьте в конструктор инициализацию:

```
Item(string n, int a) : name(n), age(a), next(nullptr) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Переделал table под вектор листов. Вот что вышло:

Структура Item

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Item
{
    string name;
    int age;

    Item(string n, int a) : name(n), age(a) { }
};

#endif // ITEM_H
```

Класс Hash

```
#ifndef HASH_H
#define HASH_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

#include "item.h"

class Hash
{
    private:
            vector<list<Item*>* > table;
            int hash(string key);

    public:
            Hash();
            ~Hash();

            void push(string key, int value);
            void pop(string name);
            Item *find(string name);
            void show();
};

#endif // HASH_H
```

Его методы:

```
#include "hash.h"


int Hash::hash(string key)
{
    int hashsum = 0;

    for(size_t i=0; i<key.length(); i++)
        hashsum += key[i];

    return hashsum % table.size();
}

Hash::Hash()
{
    table.resize(50);

    for(size_t i=0; i<table.size(); i++)
        table[i] = nullptr;
}

Hash::~Hash()
{
    table.clear();
}

void Hash::push(string key, int value)
{
    int index = hash(key);

    if(!table[index])
    {
        table[index] = new list<Item*>;
        table[index]->push_back(new Item(key, value));
    }
    else
        table[index]->push_back(new Item(key, value));
}

void Hash::pop(string name)
{
    int index = hash(name);
    Item *search = this->find(name);

    if(!table[index] || !search)
    {
        cout << "Element not found!" << endl;
        return;
    }

    table[index]->remove(search);
}

Item *Hash::find(string name)
{
    int index = hash(name);

    if(!table[index])
    {
        cout << "Element not found!" << endl;
        return nullptr;
    }

    auto it = table[index]->begin();

    while(it != table[index]->end())
    {
        if((*it)->name == name)
            return *it;

        it++;
    }

    cout << "Element not found!" << endl;
    return nullptr;
}

void Hash::show()
{
    for(size_t i=0; i<table.size(); i++)
    {
        if(table[i])
        {
            auto it = table[i]->begin();
            while(it != table[i]->end())
            {
                cout << (*it)->name << "\t" << (*it)->age << endl;
                it++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main-функция:

```
#include "hash.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Hash table;
    int choice;

    string name;
    int age;

    while(true)
    {
        cout << "\n1. Insert; 2. Find; 3. Delete; 4. Show; 5. Exit;" << endl;
        cout << "Choice: "; cin >> choice;

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: {
                        cout << "Name: "; cin >> name;
                        cout << "Age: "; cin >> age;
                        table.push(name, age);
                        break;
                    }

            case 2: {
                        cout << "Name: "; cin >> name;
                        Item *search = table.find(name);

                        if(search) cout << "Age: " << search->age << endl;
                        break;
                    }

            case 3: {
                        cout << "Name: "; cin >> name;
                        table.pop(name);
                        break;
                    }

            case 4: {
                        cout << endl;
                        table.show();
                        break;
                    }

            case 5: { exit(0); break; }
            default: { break; }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```